# Laravel 8: Keep getting eager loading with many to many relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 tables, users, roles and permissions

A user can have many roles and a role can have many permissions.
So now I made a function which checks if a user has a role which has the needed permission.

```php
public function hasPermissionTo($permission): bool
    {
        if (is_string($permission)) {
            $permission = Permission::with('roles')->firstWhere('title', $permission);
        }

        if (is_int($permission)) {
            $permission = Permission::with('roles')->firstWhere('id', $permission);
        }

        if (! $permission instanceof Permission) {
            throw new PermissionDoesNotExist;
        }
        return count(array_intersect(auth()->user()->roles->pluck('groupID')->toArray(), $permission>roles->pluck('groupID')->toArray())) > 0;
    }
```

And my roles relation in Permission model:

```php
public function roles() : BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'permission_role', 'permission_id', 'role_id');
    }
```

My code works, but I have 12 query duplicates: `` select `wcf1_user_group`.*, `wcf1_user_to_group`.`userID` as `pivot_userID`, `wcf1_user_to_group`.`groupID` as `pivot_groupID` from `wcf1_user_group` inner join `wcf1_user_to_group` on `wcf1_user_group`.`groupID` = `wcf1_user_to_group`.`groupID` where `wcf1_user_to_group`.`userID` = 13 ``

wcf1_user_group is the table for the roles, wcf1_user_to_group is the many to many relationship between roles and users, and permissions and permission_role is the other relationship.

When I dd() my $permission variable I get the relations in it.
Maybe someone has an idea, thanks.

Comment: you should add more info for your question. when and how are you calliing these `hasPermissionTo`? by the way, there is very good library for that - https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission. take a look, maybe it will be better than reinventing the bicycle.

Comment: @Roman Bobrik I know spatie permissions and the code is from their repo. The problem is, I only have 1 model to role connection and they use a morphTo relationship in model_has_permission table. And I'm pretty fixed in using different tables.